# Jetty war Deployment, 503 or 404 Error depending on web app Header

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, jetty, war

I'm trying to deploy a .war file via SSH and PSCP on a Jetty Server. I am exporting my project to a war file with Eclipse. I get a `404 Error with this configuration in the web.xml file:

```
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

However it seems to work with version 2.5 since I get a 503 Error with this configuration in my web.xml file:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

Considering my .war export options I deselected "Optimize for a specific server runtime" (because I only had Tomcat as an option) and deselected "Export source files" (with this option I always get the 404 Error no matter which webapp version I'm using).  Do I need a Jetty Library or something like that in my Project? I tried the same thing with this war: http://www.se.uni-hannover.de/pages/de:tutorials_helloworld_servlets and could instantly access it and Jetty seemed to deploy it without any problems. Looking at the .war File of this test file I do not see any differences and can only assume that I am somehow using a feature that simply won't work with the webapp version 2.5. Is there anything I could do to solve my problem? I would really appreciate any kind of help :)

And if any version Information is needed, I can only provide this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Look at the logs of the Jetty server. 503 error suggests that there is XML parsing error. Possibly illegal content in web.xml 2.5. There should be some explanation in the logs. Check what messages are displayed when you deploy your original WAR. You use Jetty 9.2 which supports servlet API v 3.1, so everything you used in web.xml 3.0 should be supported.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kWeKQC9.png Well it is something, now I at least have a specific error message. Is there simple way to tell how I could fix this just by looking at it? Do I simply have to swap to JDK 1.7?

Comment: This is easy. Jetty 9.2 supports Java 1.7. You are compiling your code to Java 1.8 (this represents major.minor version 52.0). Switch java compliance level in project settings (Java Compiler) and have another try.

Comment: Thank you so much man! It worked, finally. I should have asked a day ago... If you post your suggestions as a answer I would be happy to mark it as the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logs of the Jetty server. 503 error suggests that there is XML parsing error. Possibly illegal content in web.xml 2.5. There should be some explanation in the logs. Check what messages are displayed when you deploy your original WAR. You use Jetty 9.2 which supports servlet API v 3.1, so everything you used in web.xml 3.0 should be supported.

In case of `major.minor 52.0` errors, class file version is the cause.

Jetty 9.2 supports Java 1.7. You are compiling your code to Java 1.8 (this represents major.minor version 52.0). Switch java compliance level in project settings (Java Compiler) and have another try.